# is there any way to save the filename by following the user input? i want the file to be saved into data/<uname>.txt

Tags: c++

```
char uname[30], psw[20],fname[3],bname[30],pnumber[30];
int x,pil;

void createAcc() {
    
    ofstream f("data/"+ uname + ".txt");   //i want the file to be saved into data/uname.txt
                                           // ex: the user is input is myfile
                                           // so it will be saved into data/myfile.txt
    if(f.is_open()){
            
        f<<"Nama Depan    : "<<fname<<endl;
        f<<"Username      : "<<uname<<endl;
        f<<"Password      : "<<psw<<endl;
        f<<"Nama Belakang : "<<bname<<endl;
        f<<"Nomor Telepon : "<<pnumber<<endl;
            
    f.close();
    }
    else cout<<"error: cannot write into file"<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Don't use arrays of `char` to represent strings  (and keep in mind that a string literal (like `"data/"`) is represented as a nul-terminated array of `char`).   Use `std::string` instead - it is an object that represents a string and allows operations that are not possible (directly) with arrays.   In particular, arrays of `char` cannot be appended to each other using addition (`+`) like you are doing.   `std::string`s CAN be appended using `+`  - both to each other and (with care) to nul-terminated arrays of `char` (including string literals) and can also be initialised using string literals.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to concatenate multiple C-style strings in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64478222/how-to-concatenate-multiple-c-style-strings-in-c)

Comment: Yes, you can user input to name a file. However, you probably want to define the file name *after* you get the name from the user and not attempt to do so before.